# remove consecutively occurring elements from arraylist

Tags: java

e.g if `ArrayList` with `set1 = {"a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}`,   `ArrayList` with `set2 = {"a", "b"}`.Then remove occurrence of `a` and `b` `set1` will have `{"c", "d", "e"}`

e.g if ArrayList with set1 = {"a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}
       ArrayList with set2 = {"a", "b"}

```
   then remove occurence of a and b set1 will have {"c", "d", "e"}
```

I have tried:

```
public class test {
public static void main(String[] args){
ArrayList<String> contents = new ArrayList<String>();
contents.add("a");
contents.add("a");
contents.add("b");
contents.add("b");
contents.add("c");
contents.add("d");
contents.add("e");

ArrayList<String> delete = new ArrayList<String>();
delete.add("a");
delete.add("b");

for(String str: contents)
System.out.println(str);

System.out.println();

contains(contents, delete);

System.out.println();

for(String st: contents)
   System.out.println(st);

}

public static void contains(ArrayList<String> set1, ArrayList<String> set2 ) {

int count = 0;

OUTER:
for (int i = 0; i < set1.size() - set2.size(); i++) {
for (int j = 0; j < set2.size(); j++) {
if (!set1.get(i + j).equals(set2.get(j)))
continue OUTER;
else{
set1.remove(set1.get(i+j));                  
}

}
count++;

}        

System.out.println(count);

}
```

current Output: a
                b
                c
                d
                e
I still get a b c d e but I should only should get c d e because since a,b occurs twice it should remove both occurences.

Comment: Sounds like homework. Which is okay, but you have to show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Actually posting your code is not even as important as simply asking a question.

Comment: @NovPi good question to start your learning, please try, accept the challenge and post the answer by yourself. You'll be proud

Comment: @Radiodef for homework questions it is. SO is here to assist and explain, not to just do your homework for you. Although I agree that in this case, the question could be clarified better

Comment: why didn't you post your code in the first time you ask the question?

Comment: This is my first time using SO, I'm not that accustomed to posting.

Comment: As for the code I'm not trying to delete all occurrences of each element in set2 from set1. I want that if a,b occurs consecutively in set1, I remove a and b from set1 then increment the count. So if set1 = {"a", "a", "b", "c", "b", "a"} after removing set1.get(1) and set1.get(2) since a,b occurs consecutively I get {"a", "c", "b", "a"

Comment: @NovPi so i upvoted after posting codes.however hope you got the answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion.

1. You have two `ArrayList` as you shown.
2. Take a look at [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html), There is a handy option [List.removeAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29). Try to use that.

From `Java` doc, `removeAll()`

> Removes from this list all of its elements that are contained in the
>   specified collection (optional operation).

Edit:

***Since you have provided your*** ***effort***. You can try as follows.

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
list1.add("a");
list1.add("a");
list1.add("b");
list1.add("a");
list1.add("b");
list1.add("c");
list1.add("d");
list1.add("e");

list2.add("a");
list2.add("b");

list1.removeAll(list2);
System.out.println(list1);
```

Out put:

```
[c, d, e]
```

Comment: @Downvoter you should at least have a courage to put your reason to downvote. This question has provided his effort. I can't see any reason to not to put an answer. If you have any other issue you should leave a comment.